# php putenv restrictions on server environment, how does this affect civicrm

Tags: wordpress

I've got the email below from my hosting provider "wpengine". Is it going to affect civicrm, does civicrm rely much on putenv?

---

On July 20, 2016, we will be hardening the PHP function putenv based on industry best practices for all PHP applications.

You are receiving this message because we have detected the use of putenv on your WordPress install(s) and plugins listed below:

Plugin: civicrm

How this affects you

After Wednesday, July 20, 2016, you will no longer be able to set system-level environment variables using putenv. Any environment variables you set with putenv will be available in your WordPress site's code as it normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might if you use something other than US english, or whatever your host has set for the system-level.

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/I18n.php

But it will probably still work anyway because CiviCRM sets other variables too that have higher priority. See
https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html

Comment: Doing `grep -r putenv` on the codebase, agree `CRM/Core/I18n.php` caught the eye as a match. Almost everything else appears to be part of the test classes (which aren't used in a real site). One other *possible* issue is ([packages/Date/TimeZone.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/blob/4.7.9/Date/TimeZone.php#L286)), but I'm not certain if that's ever called.